# Alien Invasion AttributeError: 'Scoreboard' object has no attribute 'level_img'

Tags: python

I can't find the problem in my code, it says that there is an attribute error but i can't find the problem. I need help Here is a github repository link https://github.com/Hunty405/Alien-Invasion

the book I'm using "python crash course" has what it should be and i've tried to fix the code by using the code in it but i can't get it to work. i believe there is a problem with prep_high_score not being called but i am not sure how to fix it.

Sorry for not posting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hlehm\Onedrive Transfer\Python\Projects\Alien_Invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 272, in <module>
    ai.run_game()
  File "c:\Users\hlehm\Onedrive Transfer\Python\Projects\Alien_Invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 50, in run_game
    self._update_screen()
  File "c:\Users\hlehm\Onedrive Transfer\Python\Projects\Alien_Invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 258, in _update_screen
    self.sb.show_score()
  File "c:\Users\hlehm\Onedrive Transfer\Python\Projects\Alien_Invasion\scoreboard.py", line 75, in show_score
    self.screen.blit(self.level_image, self.level_rect)
AttributeError: 'Scoreboard' object has no attribute 'level_image'
```

--

```
import pygame.font

class Scoreboard:
    """A class to report scoring information"""


def __init__(self, ai_game):
    """Initialize scorekeeping attributes"""
    self.screen = ai_game.screen
    self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
    self.settings = ai_game.settings
    self.stats = ai_game.stats

    #Font settings for scoring information
    self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
    self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

    #Prepare the initial score images
    self.prep_score()
    self.prep_high_score()


def prep_score(self):
    """Turn the score into a render image"""
    rounded_score = round(self.stats.score, -1)
    score_str = "{:,}".format(rounded_score)
    self.score_image = self.font.render(score_str, True, self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

    #Display the score at the top right of the screen
    self.score_rect = self.score_image.get_rect()
    self.score_rect.right = self.screen_rect.right - 20
    self.score_rect.top = 20


def prep_high_score(self):
    """Turn the high score into a rendered image"""
    high_score = round(self.stats.high_score, -1)
    high_score_str = "{:,}".format(high_score)
    self.high_score_image = self.font.render(
        high_score_str, True, self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)


    #Center the high score at the top of the screen
    self.high_score_rect = self.high_score_image.get_rect()
    self.high_score_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
    self.high_score_rect.top = self.screen_rect.top
    


def check_high_score(self):
    """Check to see if there's a new high score"""
    if self.stats.score > self.stats.high_score:
        self.stats.high_score = self.stats.score
        self.prep_high_score()
        self.prep_level()


def prep_level(self):
    """Turn the level into a rendered image"""
    level_str = str(self.stats.level)
    self.level_image = self.font.render(
        level_str, True, self.text_color, self.settings.bg_color)

    #Posistion the level below the score
    self.level_rect = self.level_image.get_rect()
    self.level_rect.right = self.score_rect.right
    self.level_rect.top = self.score_rect.bottom + 10


def show_score(self):
    """Draw scores and level to the screen"""
    self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
    self.screen.blit(self.high_score_image, self.high_score_rect)
    self.screen.blit(self.level_image, self.level_rect)
```

Comment: Please post the error, and some sample code from your app that's referenced by the error. Unless you expect someone to download your app, figure out how to run it, do a security analysis to ensure it's safe to run, and then run it multiple times to reproduce your exact error - which you haven't posted :)

Comment: Without a full stack trace of the error, it's hard to determine the issue.  But just doing a quick search for `level_img` in `scoreboard.py` turns up nothing. So that's probably why it is saying there is no attribute `level_img`. However, there is a `level_image` so maybe that is what you need to use instead, just a guess though.

Comment: sorry, did it now @kconsiglio

Comment: also, it is supposed to be level_image but i typo'd the title @DanielleM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `AttributeError: 'Scoreboard' object has no attribute 'level_image'` is saying that your Scoreboard class has no attribute 'level_image'.

So, you'll need to add the attribute it to your `__init__` function for the that class. You also need to call the function  `self.prep_level()` as it appears that is the function that will set the value for level_image. I commented on the two lines I added.

```
 def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize scorekeeping attributes"""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.settings = ai_game.settings
        self.stats = ai_game.stats

        ### added: level_image here ###
        self.level_image = None

        #Font settings for scoring information
        self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

        #Prepare the initial score images
        self.prep_score()
        self.prep_high_score()

        ### added: call this as well since this function sets the value for level_img ###
        self.prep_level()
```

This should get it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I was too late with my answer, I just hope that it will help someone in the future.
I'm currently studying python from the same book, and I came across the same mistake.

You don't need to add the attribute, add the function. You've got all you need in there

```
def __init__(self, ai_game):
"""Initialize scorekeeping attributes"""
self.screen = ai_game.screen
self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
self.settings = ai_game.settings
self.stats = ai_game.stats

#Font settings for scoring information
self.text_color = (30, 30, 30)
self.font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 48)

#Prepare the initial score images
self.prep_score()
self.prep_high_score()

### added!!! all yo need is to ad "self.prep_level()" in here
#Prepare the level image
self.prep_level()
```